# Automatically update my webserver when I update a branch using gitlab

Tags: laravel-5, gitlab, methodology

Here is my scenario:

I have a Laravel 5.8 project with which I'm using gitlab.com to manage version control. I also set up a virtual private sever with a LAMP stack to host my site online. Currently my project has 2 branches, master and dev, and when I accept a merge request on master I enter my webserver via ssh and navigate to my project folder and issue a `git pull` command.

My question is, can this be done automatically using gitlab and avoid having to manually log into my webserver each time there is a change on the master branch? I have read up a bit but not sure if what I need is a "mirror repository" or to implement a "pipeline" as gitlab calls it.

Would greatly appreciate any orientation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to look into Jenkins. It's free and could provide the solution you're wanting.

https://jenkins.io/